# Pandas combining rows with diffrent row Names in to new df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following `df1`:

```
         A1       A2        A3        A4       B1        B2        B3      B4  \
3  0.202425  0.13495  0.202425  0.202425  0.94465  0.877175  0.877175  0.8097   

        C1      C2   ...           F3        F4        G1        G2        G3  \
3  1.21455  1.3495   ...     4.925676  4.318401  5.330526  5.600426  5.802851   

         G4        H1        H2       H3       H4  
3  5.398001  0.202425  0.067475  0.13495  0.13495  

[1 rows x 32 columns]
```

I would like to create something like this:

```
       A1       A2        A3        A4
0.202425  0.13495   0.202425  0.202425
0.94465   0.877175  0.877175  0.8097
1.21455   1.3495    1.282025  1.282025
2.429101  2.496576  2.429101  2.429101    
3.441226  3.846076  3.643651  3.643651
4.723251  4.858201  4.925676  4.925676
5.330526  5.600426  5.802851  5.802851
0.202425  0.067475  0.13495   0.13495
```

Here is my code:

```
a_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('A')]
b_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('B')]
c_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('C')]
d_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('D')]
e_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('E')]
f_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('F')]
g_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('G')]
h_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c.startswith('H')]

col_dict = dict(zip(a_cols, b_cols,c_cols,d_cols,e_cols,f_cols,g_cols,h_cols))
l=pd.concat([df1.loc[:, a_cols], df1.loc[:, b_cols], df1.loc[:, c_cols], df1.loc[:, d_cols], df1.loc[:, e_cols], df1.loc[:, f_cols], df1.loc[:, g_cols].df1.loc[:, h_cols].rename(columns=col_dict)])
print (l)
```

Somehow I can't zip together multiple lists...

Comment: How is this question different to your previous [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600342/pandas-combining-rows-with-diffrent-row-names)?

Comment: it does not work for more rows...

Comment: Then show why, SO is not a code writing service, you can't just dump requests without showing effort

Comment: sorry I have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use numpy arrays by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

You can use it, if `length` of columns is `4`.

```
print df
#         A1       A2        A3        A4       B1        B2        B3      B4  \
#0  0.202425  0.13495  0.202425  0.202425  0.94465  0.877175  0.877175  0.8097   
#
#        F1      F2        F3        F4        G1        G2        G3  \
#0  1.21455  1.3495  4.925676  4.318401  5.330526  5.600426  5.802851   
#
#         G4        H1        H2       H3       H4  
#0  5.398001  0.202425  0.067475  0.13495  0.13495  


print (df.values).reshape((5, 4))

#[[ 0.202425  0.13495   0.202425  0.202425]
# [ 0.94465   0.877175  0.877175  0.8097  ]
# [ 1.21455   1.3495    4.925676  4.318401]
# [ 5.330526  5.600426  5.802851  5.398001]
# [ 0.202425  0.067475  0.13495   0.13495 ]]

print (df.values).shape[1]
#20

print pd.DataFrame((df.values).reshape(((df.values).shape[1]/4, 4)), 
                                       columns=['A1','A2','A3','A4'])

#         A1        A2        A3        A4
#0  0.202425  0.134950  0.202425  0.202425
#1  0.944650  0.877175  0.877175  0.809700
#2  1.214550  1.349500  4.925676  4.318401
#3  5.330526  5.600426  5.802851  5.398001
#4  0.202425  0.067475  0.134950  0.134950
```